# How to change the emacs package repository?

Tags: emacs, package, emacs24

I use Emacs 24.3.1 on a Ubuntu 14.4. I'd like the `list-packages` command to list packages from the MELPA depository. I have followed the instructions [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html) and [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA), to no avail. Specifically, following the advice given in the first link I added the following lines to my ~./emacs file:

```
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (package-initialize)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
  )
```

and restarted my emacs. This didn't have any effect, so I deleted the lines above and, following the advice given in the second link, added the following lines to my ~/.emacs file:

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

I restarted my emacs, but this had no effect either.

The reason I think that these attempts had no effect is that after each attempt I listed the available packages using the `list-package` command and did not find the package highlight-chars.el which I am interested in and which appears on the list at [the MELPA website](http://melpa.org/#/).

How can I instruct the `list-packages` command to search the MELPA depository?

Comment: Don't leave out `(package-initialize)`.

Comment: If the first version of the code, there's `package-initialize`. It's not there in the second version.

Comment: @abo-abo: But the first version doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should check after restarting is the *value of the variable* in question.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `package-archives` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Whether or not it has the value you've tried to set is what's of primary interest.

If it doesn't, then presumably something else in your config is setting a conflicting value.

I would hazard a guess that you have the `package-archives` variable *customized*, and that the stored custom value is clobbering the value you're setting with `setq`.

For instance, the following init file would have the effect described:

```el
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-archives (quote (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Those `custom-set-*` forms could also be in a separate file, and therefore less obvious.

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `package-archives` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Select "Revert" and "Erase Customizations" to remove any value saved via this interface.

I'll speculate that the fact that Emacs' default initialisation of the package system happens after evaluating your init file *may* also be a factor here. People often recommend calling `(package-initialize)` in your init file but leave out the information that you want to have `(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)` in tandem with that, to prevent the initialisation happening twice. If that second initialisation occurs after the package-archives variable has changed again via customization, it might cause additional impediments to the system working the way you had wanted it to.

Comment: So here's how I ended up solving the problem. I moved the setq statement to the beginning of the .emacs file, and now it works.